# Pool: Can't open database

Tags: r, sqlite, dbi, duckdb

I am trying to use `pool` to connect to my DuckDB/SQLite database .

```
con <- pool::dbPool(
  drv = duckdb::duckdb(),
  dbname = "data",
  host = "FINAL_data.duckdb")
```

when I then type

```
dplyr::tbl(con,"data")
```

I can't open the database.

```
Error in dbplyr::as.sql(from, con) : unused argument (con)
```

So I try:

```
dplyr::tbl("data") 

Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "character"
```

So I went back to

```
con <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "FINAL_data.duckdb")
bigdf<-tbl(con,"data")
```

And this won't open the database now at all (which previously worked fine). The DB is still on disk and about 24G in size. Any thoughts as to what's going on are really appreciated!

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  duckdb_prepare_R: Failed to prepare query SELECT *
FROM "data" AS "zzz6"
WHERE (0 = 1)
Error: Catalog Error: Table with name data does not exist!
LINE 2: FROM "data" AS "zzz6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue and it seems to be an incompatibility between the `pool` and `dbplyr` version.

For version of `pool` `0.1.5` and up you need to used `dbplyr` version `2.0.0` and up.
If you use lower version of `dbplyr` e.g. `1.4.4` you need to downgrade your `pool` to e.g. `0.1.4.3`